# Reward slow/careful edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

It is clear that a lot of careful reviewers have stopped doing edit reviews. I often see statements on meta like:

> [I barely get a vote because by the time at which I decided whether or](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252206/57159)
>   not I can actually make a clear decision on the change, that change is
>   already approved.

The best reward for reviewing is knowing that your voice is being listened to; this is clearly not the case at present for careful edit reviews.

Would it be possible to introduce a **minimum review time**? However... some edit reviews can be done in a few seconds because it is clear what the outcome should be... but then again can they only be approved so quickly because they are really “too minor”?

**So my first thought is:**

Do not enable the “approved” button until the reviewer has spend at least `n` minutes looking at the edit review. **This is unlikely to work, as any value of `n` large enough to have a real effect will put off good reviewers as well.**

**My next thought is:**

Do not show an edit review task to more than the required number of reviewers until a reviewer has not responded within 5 minutes. Sometimes this will slow down the review process when someone closes the tab without at least hitting “skip” but I don’t know if that is a real problem. (A "keep alive" driven by JavaScript will at least detect a tab being closed, but will not detect someone going into a meeting.)

**But I best I have come up with so far is:**

Change the edit review “voting” to be at least `x` more people must vote for “approve” than “reject” and at least `y` people must vote to approve, then count all votes from reviewers provided they arrive within 5 minutes of there being enough reviews. (With a basic rule that `z` rejects are enough to reject the edit.)

This will delay the outcome of an edit review by 5 minutes unless the number of reviews in progress is tracked. The easy implementation is to just take when the last review task for a edit was "given out" and then wait until 5 minutes after that time. The better implementation to to keep track of all "active review tasks".

Comment: As much as I hate robo-reviewers, having to stare at an edit I know is good enough for 2 minutes will most definitely make me stop reviewing as well. So that one would be a no go for me.

Comment: The minimal review time is definitely a no-go, but I really like the suggestions to delay approving the edit for a few minutes to allow *all* reviewers to finish.

Comment: all 3 ideas do not solve the problem in my opinion. I think we should first lay out clear rules for reviewing. What is a good edit and what is not - what should be approved and what shouldn't. Once we have some rules to judge against then we could ban people for not reviewing properly just like it's done in all other queues.

Comment: @user2140173, then how would we be able to see if the reviewer reviewed properly?