# Require one high-rep approval for Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, edits

I've noticed a consistent trend in the Suggested Edits queue wherein I'll see a proposed edit that looks fairly bad, click through to look at the context, and come back to vote against only to see that it's been approved. When this happens, nearly 100% of the time the three approve votes all came from users with less than 5k rep, who are presumably new to SO. The edit audits don't really help because the audits are so blindingly bogus that only the most oblivious robo-reviewer would get caught.

I propose requiring that at least one of the votes to approve an edit come from a user with a high reputation (maybe 7.5k or 10k), and perhaps additional logic when several 3k users approve while Jon Skeet rejects. The Suggested Edits queue is always so small that this wouldn't clog it and would help squash some of the lousy proposals (and perhaps even improve their signal-to-noise ratio).

Comment: This is assuming that high-rep users will actually *see* and vote for the edit... which means it could easily be in the queue indefinitely.

Comment: @deceze I check the edits queue regularly, and it's usually very small or empty.

Comment: I've been thinking for a while now about requesting a raise in the rep barrier for approving suggested edits, this looks like a happy medium. +1

Comment: How about this - the rep of all approvers must total > some number, and must average > some other number.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252856/reward-slow-carefull-edit-reviews contains my thought on this problem.

Comment: @BobJarvis I like the total rep idea. Imposing a lower limit on the average could cause an obviously good edit to go unapproved, despite high rep approvals, because a large number of low rep users also approved it, dragging down the average.

Comment: Having 5 4.5kers vote to approve isn't the same as having 2 3kers and a single 10k+.

Comment: More than high rep, we need people with high success rates and previous votes.

Comment: @AnubianNoob How would you quantify that? "Rep" is the SE flattened proxy for that sort of thing.

Comment: I'd like some stats on this before I'd agree that this is a good idea. Personally, I think we just need to get better audits - [Add "too minor" audits to review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183977)

Comment: I doubt 7.5k or 10k _reputation_ has to do anything with _quality of review_ . So I think it's better to add measuring of review fails (we have such mechanics right now, when system is proposing fake edits). If it's too high - then restrict user from reviewing for a while.

Comment: @AlmaDo That already happens - users get banned for failing too many review audits.

Comment: The fact that i have high rep doesn't mean i make a good reviewer.

Comment: A while ago I proposed that we take into account flag weight (I'm aware this isn't displayed to the user, but I believe it still exists)  more instead of rep as that is probably a better indicator that someone has taken the time to review correctly.

Comment: @chrylis what is "SNR"?

Comment: @Cupcake Signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: @AlmaDo I'm just reporting my personal observation, which is that when clearly bad edits get approved, there are usually no higher-rep reviewers involved.

Comment: @KevinB high rep doesn't necessarily mean you'll be good at ***anything,*** but we give high-rep users all sorts of different, powerful privileges anyways, because it's a ***good-enough approximation*** of how trustworthy a user is. It's not *perfect,* but it's good enough. I don't see how restricting edit-review privileges to ***fewer*** users could be any ***worse*** than the current situation, where it's given out to ***too many*** un-trustworthy users.

Comment: More than a few times I've said to myself, *"How the **hell** did this edit get approved?!"* Most of the time what that happens, it's very late at night (in my timezone...)

Comment: @KevinB Indeed, one could argue that the best reviewers are the ones who spend all their time in the review queues; since that doesn't give them any rep, they would be expected to stall out just above the threshold for doing reviews.

Comment: If rep isn't a good enough indication of how good a reviewer someone is, perhaps some other metrics could be used instead or in addition: approval/reject ratio, # of reviews, # of times they have approved edits rejected by others etc. Maybe have a magic algorithm come up with a "trusted reviewer" status and make the votes of people with this status count more

Answer (score 5):

I just went through the suggested edit queue, and then backed through it to check the rep of the other reviewers.  It's true that all of the approve votes came from users with less than 5k - actually less than 3k - rep.

**However,** all of the reject votes also came from users with less than 3k rep.

So it looks like most of the reviewers have "low" rep, whether they approve or reject.  That means there's no reason to think that "low" rep reviewers do any worse than "high" rep reviewers.

On the other hand, this also means that there is reason to believe that if you required high rep reviewer votes, the queue might get clogged.  That doesn't seem like a good thing to risk.

I think a better solution would be to have the invalid edit audits require actually reading through the edit, instead of essentially all being cases of vandalism.

Comment: Would the mix of reviewers change if edits did not get approved so fast?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I can't speak for the high-rep users, but after only a couple of months, I can say that I'm already partly frustrated by how the edit review queue works. I still do reviews, but it seems likely that I'll get tired enough of it that I'll stop completely at some point. So if high rep users stopped reviewing, I can completely sympathize.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give a similar suggestion inspired mostly from the comments: Require a minimum total rep, with a minimum number of people. Also require a minimum total rep held by the lower half (in rep) of the reviewers, so that:

1. Higher rep people aren't going to guarantee its passage regardless of others' thoughts, and
2. Lower rep people aren't able to plague the site with bad approved edits.

Comment: reputation is not a good indicator whether you a good or bad reviewer.

Comment: How would you judge aptitude at reviewing edits? Especially algorithmically, because this *will* have to be computer-enforced.

Comment: data.stackexchange.com can give you some data about the suggested edits approvals and rejections.