# Should question titles generally be questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits, title

I know we're not going to enforce this in general, but there's currently a lot of noise in the review queue from user [Anand Solanki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2842136/), whose edit history consists almost entirely of editing question titles from questions into statements.

Should we be approving these edits? Many times they marginally improve the capitalization of the title, but removing the question seems like a bad thing to me.

I see no reason to forcibly turn statements into questions, but going the other way seems wrong.

Comment: Those edits are *too minor* and should be rejected. They are a) not helpful and b) leave other errors in place. By the looks of it he'll soon enough run into a suggested edit ban.

Comment: We don't have much time to stop him: 66 more rep and his edits will bypass reviews entirely. Do you know if someone left him a comment about this issue?

Comment: *Anand Solanki had 538 edit suggestions approved, and 165 edit suggestions rejected*. Please let him run into the ban sooner than later...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Wasn't that at 3k?

Comment: @Xeo, nope, [2K](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Heh. I rejected one of his edits just now simply on the basis that he called it "Improved Formatting".

Comment: Does the editor see custom reject reasons?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll

Comment: I left him a comment under his latest edit. We'll see what comes out of it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @Collin: Only if he actually cares enough to review the outcomes of his suggested edits. I'm pretty sure he doesn't give a flying... fly. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor

Comment: The question that we should really be asking is: why the heck are those edits not rejected?

Comment: @Jefffrey, oh, we know the answer to that. We know it very well.

Comment: Neat, he's now repeatedly attempting the same edit on a post after getting rejected. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4887839 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4887841 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4887857

Comment: As days pass by I'm more and more inclined to reject any edit that has "Improved Formatting" in its description. It starts reading like "This edit is some silly crap that I'm doing just to farm rep formatting"

Comment: @BoltClock: You haven't given them a manual timeout yet then?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Was about to, but then he suggested [one last one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4887860), which I rejected, and now he's edit banned.

Comment: Excellent. Now we only have to wait for him to complain about his situation on Meta.

Comment: Maybe we should also remove all the reputation gained by those edits? ~1K of unfair reputation is too much.

Comment: @Jefffrey: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh my god

Comment: Tell ya what though it's nice to discover there's a meta.se post I can link to when people keep insisting on this backticking crap

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: When I have "improved formatting" as an edit reason, it *always* involves improving actual formatting.  Now I may have to change that to something else, thanks to users like this.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: And so I suppose edit reasons should be "first impressions" of the edited, and should *never* be judged alone.  But to robo-reviewers, unfortunately, it's good enough.

Comment: FWIW I've sent the user a very, *very* stern warning about this, especially in light of his... defiant behavior. Let's just say I make good on my threats.

Comment: Since we are not on Jeopardy, I do not see why title form should matter as long as it's descriptive and concise.

Comment: @PM77-1: In short, this user's edits aren't improving the post greatly. If he fixes 1 mistake, he's leaving 10 unfixed. That's why they should be rejected.

Comment: @AmalMurali - I'm not defending the person that makes unnecessary edits.  I'm just stating that relevant and concise titles should be left alone in whatever form they are.  It simply does not matter whether they formulated like questions or not.

Comment: I'm not nearly familiar enough with the SE data-mining tools to construct the appropriate query, but is there any straightforward way to determine the max rep of the users who approved the crappy edits? This is exactly the sort of scenario I was trying to describe in [my proposal to try to sanity-check edit approvals](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253992/require-one-high-rep-approval-for-suggested-edits).

Comment: Just FYI, I ran across another person doing the exact same thing as Anand. He made some minor edits, labelled the suggestion "improved formatting and grammar fixes" for removing one extra word and getting rid of an extra tab on a semi-colon. I wouldn't have thought anything of it if I hadn't come across this question. I checked out his profile, and he's been doing this incessantly since about yesterday. Fernando Carvalhosa is the name of the user.

Answer (score 42):

I don't think question titles must forcibly be phrased in question or statement form. Titles can work fine in both forms. (Titles don't work at all in forms like "names of random language features strung together followed by one of issue, problem, or question", though)

I do think that this user's editing activity is nothing but noise and in some cases actively *harmful* as some edits remove important information that makes the titles usefully descriptive.

Comment: I agree, as long as the title is *descriptive* (and preferably concise) it doesn't matter if it is formulated as a question. However, I don't think **"How do I.."** belongs in a title (a pet peeve of mine).

Comment: @AndyG, I agree. Very generic beginnings to questions ("How do I...", "What's wrong", "What  is...") are often unnecessary. If the title is more clear as a question, make it a question; if it is more clear as a phrase, make it a phrase; if it is a tie, ask `urand`.

Answer (score 5):

> Should we be approving these edits?

No. Edit suggestions that don't make an objective improvement should be rejected as noise, and the post should be left the way its author intended. Rejecting poor quality edits will hopefully encourage future edits to be more convincingly useful.

But it's obvious why these edits are happening and will keep happening. Someone found something they could do, it was really easy, and the system rewarded them with streams of rep for doing it, as if saying "Well done, you're useful!". I hate when people farm for rep with masses of suggested edits when often all they're doing is adding backticks around `random nouns`. But the system keeps rewarding them for doing this so I can't even blame them.

Comment: I won't edit a post just to add backticks, but backticks on inline code (rather than as a generic phrase highlighter) does (imo) improve readability. If there are, say, spelling and paragraphing issues too, that's enough for an edit for me. (Agree with the point about rep-farming, though).

Answer (score 0):

No, I think what he's doing is simply *wrong*. We are *Questions* and Answers site, and as such, question titles should be formulated as questions.

If his edits don't change anything besides the title in a way he does, they should be ultimately rejected.

Comment: No, question **titles** do not have to be questions. In fact, they often work better if they aren't formulated as questions, because they're titles for the whole thread, which includes not only the question but also its answers.

Comment: @Gilles In one of the Olafur's post there was a great remark about how the question in the title tells a lot about what's really asked. I still think that they *should* be formulated as questions, at least most of the time. The fact that the question thread has answers is obvious enough for me. Even better, it doesn't suggest it's a *discussion* about some topic.

Comment: I'm familiar with the debates on MSE — [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648) is the one post that I recommend on the topic because has some basis in actual UX studies. Having a title that makes it clear that this is not a discussion is pointless — by and large people aren't looking for questions, they're looking for answers, and they don't care if the answers came about because someone asked a question, or in a blog post, or in a discussion or whatever.

Comment: @Gilles I've seen people treating SO answer box as forum post enough times to not treat that distinction as "pointless". SO is not a discussion place, and what people visiting it randomly *think* it should contain isn't that relevant for me.

Comment: But only a tiny, tiny minority of people want to interact. The vast majority of people are just reading and don't care how the content came about. We aren't writing for the small minority of people who participate on SE, we're writing for everyone who looks for information on the Internet.

Answer (score -5):

**Generally**, yes, titles as questions tend to be more descriptive.

Let's take [this arbitrary example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4887860):

> Convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime

Ok. Convert things to stuff, right. Wait, what about it? Do you want to know how to do it? Do you have code to do it that's not working? Are you trying to find a better way?

Now if you were to ask a question, it would hopefully be one of these:

> How do I ... (although many people probably use this for the latter two as well)
>   How can I fix my code to ...
>   Is there a better way to ...

Much better.

But **not always** - if the title starts off with something like "Can you provide", then you're *probably* (but not necessarily) going in the wrong direction with your title

Comment: “Convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime” is a better title than “How do I convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime?”. Having the words “how do I” at the very beginning even though they don't affect the meaning of the title is a waste of attention. The edit you link to is too minor — there were plenty of other things wrong in the post, including the title not being a good summary of the question. But in principle this example proves the opposite — the non-question version is better.

Comment: Better still would be semi-reasonable capitalization, and the odd preposition: _Convert a LinkedIn timestamp to a MySQL datetime?_ I'd prefer a serif font for the capital I in LinkedIn, but that's bearable.

Comment: @Gilles My argument in the answer is all I can say for why that is a bad title, and I stand by it. And I hope you won't try to argue that there aren't some really terrible titles out there - I mean "Please need a little help (probably stupid)", "Regular expressions, capture group", "Algorithm implementation", "SQL SERVER 2008 R2 issue" (some recent wonderful titles) - if people were to actually get into the habit of phrasing titles as questions, we might get less titles like those. I don't know how this example proves anything. Also, **we are asking questions after all**.

Comment: @Dukeling These examples are horrible titles, but it's not the fact that they aren't questions that makes them horrible. “Can you help with regular expression?” isn't any better.

Comment: @Gilles I wouldn't really mind that much whether it's a good question title and a good non-question title (although some questions IMO only lend themselves to either one or the other), but I personally think the "let's ask a question" **mindset** makes for a **way** better title **on average** - I actually think the example you picked is the most promising of the lot - if you were a bit misguided about what a ([so]) title's supposed to be, that's actually a pretty good title - if the type of user using such a title were to think "let's ask a question", I'm sure they'd come up with good ones.

Comment: I think "How to" is better than "How do I", as it shows the writer is writing a generic question, and not just for themselves. I agree with @Dukeling though - "Convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime" is more of a theme, and less so posing a problem. I wouldn't edit it if it was the only issue with a post, but the question form seems to make more sense (imo, of course).