# Are Edit Reviewers Forced to Read Edit Comments?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, edit-summary

Sometimes I can't believe peer reviewers for editing actually take any notice whatsoever.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5937099) review is probably going to be rejected because the reviewers don't read.

I have clearly stated I'm including additional information from the OP that was included in the comments on an answer.

Are edit reviewers forced to read edit comments?

**Edit:** Actually, this sounds like a very good idea! [Reward slow/careful edit reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252856/reward-slow-careful-edit-reviews)

**Another Edit:** A [second attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5937503) (but with a longer edit comment) was approved very quickly indeed, including by a reviewer who rejected the original edit. I had a chortle to myself!

Comment: This question doesn't really have much value, since you can't force people to do anything here. You're just concerned with the fact that reviewers don't/didn't read your edit summary... and turned that into a rant-question it seems.

Comment: @Werner The question was "Are edit reviewers forced to read edit comments?" Do you have an answer? I guess not. I also get annoyed with users who don't read questions, but I'll use another post on meta for that!

Comment: Don't get annoyed. But then again, I can't force you.

Comment: How could you possibly force people to read something? I'd also be grateful if you could capitalise the personal pronoun i when editing to I.

Comment: In the same way you could put massive banners at the top of every website and people would read those? You're talking about marketing ploys not forcing it - I'd be more likely to ignore overly intrusive methods of displaying/checking because that's what the internet has trained me to do.

Comment: @Ben Well, you wouldn't make a very good reviewer then!

Comment: I read them if it's not clear from the diff what is being edited, and why. I don't think it would make sense to force reviewers to read them (if that's even possible). They are there, and it's up to the reviewer to decide if they need the information or not. In the linked example, I would read it, to try and understand where the new content comes from.

Comment: Amazing that a 2k+ person actually added `Edit` in the second one!

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I know. What can you do but sigh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view that you see in the suggested edit review page is roughly what reviewers get when they review the edit.  So, the edit comment is fairly prominent and difficult to miss but shorter comments can get lost.  Take a look again at your 2 comments

> [image]
>
> [image]

I'll say the reviewers goofed on this as your first edit seemed valid, but when reviewing edits from users adding info to posts, it can be easy to miss the comment and assume the editors is trying to add new information.

The description from your first edit is extremely brief and barely a sentence.  It is short enough, it gets lost in the clutter of the page.  Your 2nd comment is much better and explains in a bit more details what the edit is for, where it came from, and why it is necessary.  It is long enough that is stands out, making it more difficult to miss.

The lesson here is if you want to make an edit that changes the post based on info from another source, try to be as briefly descriptive as possible and don't just write enough to get past the minimum.  While I have no data to support this, my personal experience in reviewing is an editor who makes no effort to provide a good edit description for their suggested edit probably didn't invest much time in editing the post and is not going to have made a good edit - effectively it is predisposing the reviewer to rejecting the edit.  Make your reasoning stand point and make the reviewer notice your description.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is a "No". Reviewers are not *required* or *forced* to read comments. Some do and act accordingly. Some don't and act based on their instinct. Some don't and merely act on the idea of [an](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian) [impending](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward). The best you can hope for is that reviewers *do* read the comments and make their decision based on that, *as well as* the edited content.

If things don't seem to be handled appropriately, either bring it up in chat or here on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) for moderators to handle/discuss (like you did).