# Suggested Edit not Approved or Found Helpful

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I thought I'd reviewed this particular question: [Dynamically convert currency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26148297/1536038)

This is what I did (as far as I remember):

- I removed a tag from the title
- Styled and corrected the formula (because it was giving an error)
- Retagged to contain only [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency) and [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

Now it turns out that the post only has a styled formula.

Was there something wrong with my suggested edit? Did I submit the suggested review at all?

Comment: You may see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5961807

Comment: Ok, thanks, been around for a while but couldn't see it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit was sent to the review queue and was [rejected and edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5961807) by one user and 1 other rejected it.

You can see your history of suggestions via your profile > activity > [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536038/jacob-jan-tuinstra?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).  From this location you'll see the link to the suggested edit at the top.

Comment: Man, these are hars comments. Makes me wonder to continue reviewing posts....here on SO.

Comment: Should I edit my post and ask why: _This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability_?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I'm not exactly sure why this was declined, it could be the use of so many tags - the person reviewing might not have seen the relevance of them.  I don't think I would have declined it though.

Comment: How come the bot told the same thing?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra the bot didn't say that, the message is actually from "ArtOfWarfare".  The rejection by "Community" is because "ArtOfWarfare" rejected and edited the post himself.

Comment: @bluefeet only 1 other editor rejected.  The 2nd was Community.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah, indeed...

Comment: @psubsee2003 You're right, it's way too early here. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Can you reinstate my suggestions, or do I need to do it again?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I took care of it for you.  If you want feel free to comment on the question explaining why the tags aren't needed.

Comment: Can you remove the last bracket from this pieceof the formula please still: ("eurgbp")? Can't make such a small edit....

Comment: I would have left Google sheets, it was there twice, feels like the author wanted people with knowledge on it to see it despite the question being, or not, directly linked to it... unless there's no reason someone with Google Sheets knowledge would be able to answer it.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra done and Jonathan done.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau google-sheets will be made a synonym !! See: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest. Quite often, people throw in the excel tag as well. That's why I'm reviewing the post.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Good to know, removed it.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I went ahead and approved that tag synonym, maybe that will help clear up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since many people in the suggested review queue will review edits on tags they are not familiar with, when removing tags, it is best to leave a proper, [harder to miss](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272985/773623) comment on why the tags are not useful for the question.

In this particular case, you remove from the title the tag and remove the tag itself (Google Sheets). After doing that, the question can't be searched with Google Sheets, which the author seemed to want. That alone could be the reason people rejected it.

As first said, a good comment that state why a tag isn't needed usually help reviewer make a better decision on the tags change.

Comment: See my profile on Web Applications, I know what I'm talking about. If other people don't, then they have to skip the review post.

Comment: I'm not disputing you having or not the knowledge here but a reason it was rejected and how to possibly avoid that in your future edits.