# Suggested Edit Rejection

Tags: discussion

I submitted an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6071584) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548311/ie8-adds-a-second-to-a-google-custom-searchbox) and while the edit was approved by the OP, I noticed that one of the reviewers rejected it for `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.`

I'm curious why the reviewer might have thought my edit was destructive, when the only changes were to format the tags so that they appeared in the question.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I bet the reviewer saw it was one of those dodgy audits, and rejected accordingly.

Comment: I actually received this very edit as part of my queue and skipped it because I had no idea where the `gcse` stuff was coming from. When you look at the rendered output, it looks like the `gcse` tags are being added in from where nothing existed before, and your edit for "fixing formatting" to me, didn't actually appear like format fixes, but addition of content.

Answer (score 24):

The reviewer probably just wasn't paying attention and didn't look at the Markdown diff, where it would have been obvious that all you were doing was making the code formatted properly. In the rendered diff, it looks like you're adding code since it was parsed as HTML in the original version and thus not shown when rendered.

So yeah, you did the right thing, don't worry about it.

Comment: This is why I review edits in markdown by default.  90% of the time it shows you exactly what you need to know.  I flip over to rendering to verify the effects of formatting and sometimes when the diff highlighting gets confused.

Answer (score 16):

The reviewer who rejected your edit was wrong and [Andrew's point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275250/suggested-edit-rejection/275251#275251) about the reviewer not paying attention to the Markdown version of the edit is spot on.

But you could have done a lot more to help the reviewers.  Your edit description was precisely "fixed formatting".  With such a poor comment, you are lucky your edit wasn't rejected completely.  That comment is extremely common and one of the absolute worst comments you can make because it tells the reviewer absolutely nothing.

> [image]

I've spoken about this [issue before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272976/are-edit-reviewers-forced-to-read-edit-comments/272985#272985) as [has Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274449/clarification-for-suggested-edit-rejection/274454#274454).  Edit comments aren't just there for the sake of being there.  They provide a valuable service to the reviewers and providing a good one help you help them understand the context of the edit.  The edit comment is extremely important for reviewers to help explain what you are doing and why.

Yes, there are plenty of cases where it may be blindingly obvious what you did (as is the case here only when looking at the markdown version of the edit), but there are far more cases where it is less obvious what you are doing and why (as is the case here only when looking at the rendered output version of the edit).

When text appears out of nowhere, the reviewer may be quick to press the reject button, but a good editor will check the comment to see if there was a reason.

Had you provided a more descriptive comment such as:

> Added code ticks to HTML tags so they appear in the rendered version of the question.

Someone probably would have been much less quick to hit the reject button.

Comment: _"With such a poor comment, you are lucky your edit wasn't rejected completely."_ Edits shouldn't be accepted / rejected solely on the comment that accompanies it. The reviewer should've used markdown mode. -1

Comment: @Cerbrus the comment is important to provide context.  Was the reviewer who rejected it wrong, absolutely, but if there was a better comment, that reviewer might have done his job.  The point is use the tools that you are provided to do a thorough job because you can't always count on the reviewers doing their job right

Comment: I can understand the benefit of more descriptive comments and generally if it is a more complicated/non-obvious change, I will try to describe it. From my perspective, it seemed like an obvious change and I guess I assumed that most edit reviewers would look at the markdown.

Comment: @JGrice you can't assume anything.  The reviewers are a mixed bag.  Sometimes you get good ones, sometimes you don't, so everything you can do to hit them over the head with the correct information will help.

Comment: I know, upon looking at the edit in question in its final rendered form, that I would have been confused.  Whether I would have looked at the markdown to resolve that confusion probably depends on the day.  If a descriptive comment had been used as pointed out in this answer, I would surely have looked at the markdown and done the right thing.  As in all things on this site, make an effort to do the best job possible to produce the best end result.

Comment: -1 The editor said **exactly** what he did. No more, no less. It may be a very common comment for edits but that's perhaps because that **is** one of the most common edits being made? I think the users who edit formatting should got a medal, at the very least. Putting an extra burden on them seems counter-productive.

Comment: @KonradViltersten how in the world is it extra burden to type something more meaningful that "fixed formatting".  And it doesn't help that "fixed formatting" is one of the most over used and inaccurate edit comments in my experience.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hmmm... Because it **is** more work than just typing in a **perfectly clear and correct** two-words' description? I think your question answers itself. In fact, if I see "fixed formatting" and I still require more information, that's probably a sign that I shouldn't review anything at the moment. The OP was to sloppy to format well. The reviewer was too lazy to actually check it out. But hey, let's blame the guy who did the corrections.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I never blamed anyone, especially the OP here.  All I did is suggest that he was lucky it wasn't rejected.  The reviewer who rejected it was clearly wrong and failed to do his job.  The entire point is that you can't fix the reviewer problem so you need to hit them over the head with a good description so they pay attention.  It is an unfortunate fact of life given the current inconsistencies in the review queue.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The point is not to "blame" the user who suggested the edit. The point is to give information and suggest a change that is within that user's power to make, and will give better results.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I realize that I worded my thought inadequately. I meant "put responsibility for XXX on the editor", not "put blame for XXX on the editor". I think we agree on the facts but have a different view of where the change should be applied. I think that we **can** fix the reviewer problem. We just choose not to - because it's easier to make the editor do even more job. Please note that I'm not arguing for nor against that. I'm just saying that since we're agreed that the reviewer did wrong, the reviewer should be the subject of change.

Comment: @AirThomas I see the point and there's definitely something to it. I'm just opposed to the the idea that *being **able** to contribute more* is equated to *being **expected** to contribute more*. By the same logic, it's in the reviewer's power to make a change too. I think that sloppy edits, flaggings and close votes should be punished. It's way to easy to click without thinking. I think that we're talking about different aspects - I'm speaking principally and you pragmatically. So, in fact, we agree.    :)

Comment: Not saying that the reviewer's actions were appropriate, but the majority of suggested edit audits I've seen had a comment similar to that ("improved formatting", "better grammer (sic)", etc.). Also, the editor could have done more to improve the formatting of the post. If you wanted a better comment, I think something like "fix rendering of HTML tags" strikes good balance between length and usefulness.